# Trouble with SVG editing functionality in Angular application

Tags: svg-edit

Is there is any documentation how we can implement svgEdit in angular? plz mention or type the complete process for implemnting this editor in angular app
npm i svgedit

I have tried to use it in angular application but facing a lot of issues